# Submitting an iPad application without Signup Process

Tags: ios

I am working on an application, which requires authentication (username and password). The user creation is done from a backend system.

So I would like to know if signup process is mandatory for application which require login/authentication?

I would be able to provide a test account to Apple to test my application for the approval process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not necessary to have a signup process and during the whole approval process you have to take care of thing that encourages a user to `signup` or buy `subscription` from your website.

I recently have gone through same issues, my app got rejected, but now it is in `AppStore`.

Refer to my this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536184/362310 and my application is **[ICD-10 Search Version 1.0.0](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icd-10-search/id718845762)**

Answer (score 3):

There are apps on the AppStore that require login, but don't have sign up.
As always it's up to the reviewer, but as long as you provide test login credentials to Apple, you'll probably be ok.

Here's one
  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/storyworks/id620068637?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to create an account for Apple app tester to let him to look into all your app content.
As @Andrew said to you do not need to provide a sign up system on your app.